# r geom polygon coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the correct way to enter coordinates with geom_polygon?

In this plot I would like to draw 2 rectangles.

One going from .5 to 1.5 on the x axis and 148 to 161 on the y axis.

The other going from 1.5 to 2.5 on the x axis and 339 to 352 on the y axis.

The coordinates in the polygon() below work but I'd like to confirm how the coordinates must be entered.  Below the coordinates are entered with the bottom line of each rectangle first 148 148 339 339 are entered and then the top line of each rectangle are entered: 161 161 352 352.  Is that how the coordinates must be entered - bottom line first then top line?

```
plot(1, type="n", main="test",
     xlim=c(0, 5), xlab="y",
     ylim=c(0, max( 0,400   )    ), ylab="")

polygon(
x=c(0.5 ,1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5),
y= c(148, 148, 339, 339, 352, 352, 161, 161),
col = "blue", border = NA)
```

When I enter all 4 coordinates for each rectangle for the first rectangle first and then all 4 coordinates for the second rectangle the plot is wrong:

```
plot(1, type="n", main="test",
     xlim=c(0, 5), xlab="y",
     ylim=c(0, max( 0,400   )    ), ylab="")

polygon(  x=c(.5,1.5,.5,1.5,1.5,2.5,1.5,2.5 ), y=c(148,148,161,161,339,339,352,352   ),
          col = "red", border = NA)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mention `geom_polygon` and tagged [tag:ggplot2], but your code is base R graphics. Which are you intending to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a base `plot` question rather than `ggplot2`

`polygon` is trying to to draw a single polygon rather than the two you want.  It is also assuming that the points are in order, and that the last point is connected to the first point

So your second example might work better if you separated the rectangles and reordered the points, perhaps trying

```
plot(1, type="n", main="test",
     xlim=c(0, 5), xlab="y",
     ylim=c(0, max(0, 400)), ylab="")

polygon(x=c(0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5), y=c(148, 148, 161, 161),
        col = "red", border = NA)
polygon(x=c(1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5), y=c(339, 339, 352, 352),
        col = "red", border = NA)
```

so rather than

[image]

you would get

[image]

which is what I assume you want

Comment: This code works: polygon(
x=c(0.5 ,1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5),
y= c(148, 148, 339, 339, 352, 352, 161, 161),
col = "blue", border = NA) as I mentioned in the post.  What is the order you are referring to in this code?

Comment: @user2821029 your "blue" example only works because (a) you have ordered the points more helpfully and (b) you have no border so do not see the connections from (1.5,148) to (1.5,339) or from (1.5,352) to (1.5 161).  Try using `border = "green"` to see what I mean

Comment: so if you don't want a border,  the order you are referring to that will work is bottom border first left to right  followed by top border right to left like this:  polygon(
x=c(0.5 ,1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5),
y= c(148, 148, 339, 339, 352, 352, 161, 161),
col = "blue", border = NA)

Comment: @user2821029 that works with the better order, because of the edges lining up on `x=1.5`.It is a little unnatural as you are drawing half the bottom rectangle then the top rectangle and the other half of the bottom rectangle.  It could be harder to maintain than drawing two rectangles